# How do I get xsl to return just a portion of a field to the right of the hyphen?

Tags: xslt-1.0

I'm working on an xsl template in shipworks.   I was able to make this simple code to create a text file 'pick list' that I could use.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nl "&#xd;&#xa;"> ]>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"             xmlns:sw="http://www.interapptive.com/shipworks" extension-element-prefixes="sw">
<xsl:import href="ShipWorks2\System\Common" />

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

<!-- -->
<!-- Start of processing -->
<!-- -->

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="//Order/Item">
<xsl:sort order="descending" select="../Total" data-type="number" />
<xsl:sort order="descending" select="../Number" data-type="number" />
<xsl:value-of select="SKU" />,<xsl:value-of select="Quantity" /><xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Yeah, I know, really great huh!?  Hey, that took me forever to get right!   As you can see, it's making a list of SKUs.  Well, each of my SKU's looks something like this:

BLAH-BLAH-PRODUCTSKU

I was wondering if there was a way to get ONLY the 'PRODUCTSKU' out of that value, and cut off everything before the last - character.

In looking around online, I saw the substring-after-last function.  I'm wondering if I could use that?  I tried putting that in there, but I think I'm missing something in regards to a declaration or whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

In the place of

```
<xsl:value-of select="SKU" />
```

Replace the below code. It should work,

```
<xsl:variable name="input">
        <xsl:value-of select="SKU" />
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="replace($input,'^(.)+?(PRODUCTSKU)$','$2')"/>
```